# Transfer real Ether using Api

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ether, private-blockchain

I want to purchase some Ether from Kraken and then transfer some Ether(Real) to different accounts if they win(Using Kraken API).

Do I really need a blockchain for such scenario ? I don't want to mine anything. Just purchase and then rewards some users.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to purchase some Ether from Kraken and then transfer some
>   Ether(Real) to different accounts if they win(Using Kraken API).

There is a lot of [wrappers around Kraken API](https://www.kraken.com/help/api#example-api-code). 
With Kraken API you able to buy\sell and withdraw ETH.

[`Kraken API documentation`](https://www.kraken.com/help/api)

> Do I really need a blockchain for such scenario ?

No, you don't need the blockchain.

<sub>[What is Blockchain?](https://www.coindesk.com/information/what-is-blockchain-technology/)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know we can withdraw but is it possible to transfer Ether to different accounts via API ? In which scenarios private/public blockchain is required ? For mining only ?

Comment: You can't transfer eth by using Kraken API between eth wallets, only withdrawal are allowed. Your second question is unclear for me.

Comment: I am developing a game where I can award/transfer some Ether to different users who have an Ethereum wallet. How can I achieve this without blockchain ? Any other current exchange websites supports transfer of Ether between eth wallets ?